# Post to Webhook yields 20277 error during handshake 0x80090326

Tags: slack-api, sslhandshakeexception

This works on my local machine but when deployed I get get the above handshake error.

Call is POST https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy

Thoughts?

Comment: In case this can help, since November 15th 2023 I had an handshake_failure (SSLHandshakeException) when running in prod with Java 8. 

I was able to make it work by changing the version of Java to 11. With Java 8 it was working on my local machine not in Google Cloud Dataflow.